# Get a value error when I submit a post form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to make a submit form for a django based web app i am building. However, when I press submit I get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/create

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'posts',
 'bootstrap3']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/wtreston/GDrive/Django/blog/posts/views.py" in post_create
  15.         instance = form.save(commit=False)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  448.                     'created' if self.instance._state.adding else 'changed',

Exception Type: ValueError at /create
Exception Value: The Post could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

This is my html file for the create form:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block title %}Create new Post | {{ block.super}}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Create Post</h1>

<form method = 'POST' action = '' class = 'form'>{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="post_title">Post Title</label>
    <input  class="form-control" id="post_title" placeholder="Post Title">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="post_content">Post Content</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Post Content"></textarea>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
  </div>-->

  <button type="submit" name="your_name" value="your_value" class="btn-link">Go</button>


</form>


{% endblock content %} %}
```

This is my create view in views.py:

```
def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return(redirect("posts:post_timeline"))

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid and request.POST:
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return(HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url()))

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }

    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)
```

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `if form.is_valid()` `is_valid()` is callable.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner What do you mean by this?

Comment: You forget brackets after `is_valid`. Do this `is_valid()`.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I did this and now when I click "Create Post" it refreshes the post, but doesnt create the post.

Comment: Try to remove `and request.POST` in if statement. Just `if form.is_valid():`.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner still does the same thing

Comment: Probably something wrong with your html. Try to render form in html like this: {{form.as_table}}

Answer (score 0):

This may help :-

```
from .forms import YourFormClass

def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:#If this condition is without checking POST request
        return(redirect("posts:post_timeline"))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YourFormClass(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return(HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url()))

        else:
             #Do something
             #OR
             form = YourFormClass()


    context = {
        "form": form,
    }

    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)
```